# Can not upload image to server fetching PHP from react

Tags: php, reactjs, image

I am trying to upload images using PHP fetch from react but failed any help will be appreciated. the response I receive is all the echo in PHP script. 
I think PHP is not able to receive the form data

```js
  query(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    const formData= new FormData()
    formData.append('fileToUpload',this.state.picLocation)
    formData.append('text','test')
    console.log(formData)
    fetch('http://martnext.com/imageupload/upload.php',{
      method:'POST',
      headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
          },
      body:formData
    })
    .then((response)=>response.text())
    .then((resp) =>{
      console.log(resp)
    }

  )
  }
```

Comment: You're definitely on the right track. What's the picLocation prop look like? I wrote a blog post a while back that may be helpful to you:

https://medium.com/@ariel.salem1989/how-to-upload-multiple-files-react-native-e9577a5de106

Comment: handlePicLocation(e) {
    console.log(e.target.files[0])
    this.setState({picLocation:e.target.files[0]})

  }

Comment: How does your endpoint look like?

Answer (score 0):

i fixed it by adding

```js
      headers: {
            'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
          },
```

my php endpoint looks like this

```js
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");

//http_response_code(201);
//echo json_encode(array("message" => $_FILES["file"]));
//"name","type","tmp_name","error","size"


$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo json_encode("File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".");
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo json_encode("File is not an image.");
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
//if (file_exists($target_file)) {
//    echo json_encode(array("message" => "File already exists"));
//    $uploadOk = 0;
//}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo json_encode(array("message" => "Sorry, your file is too large."));
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo json_encode(array("message" => "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed."));
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo json_encode(array("message" => "Sorry, your file was not uploaded."));
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo json_encode(array("message" => "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.http://bookmychhutti.com/imagepost/".$target_file));
    } else {
        echo json_encode(array("message" => "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file."));
    }
}
?>
```